# How manually serialize objects uses wcf display name attribute?

Tags: .net, xml, wcf

My WCF webservice must return xml file for download, for that functionality i need serialize list of objects from one class. Here that class definition:

```
[DataContract]
    public class ReportItemDriversPerAffiliate : IReportItemDriversPerAffiliate
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "affiliate_name")]
        public string AffiliateName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "affiliate_city")]
        public string AffiliateCity { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "affiliate_state")]
        public string AffiliateState { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "drivers_count")]
        public int DriversCount { get; set; }
    }
```

And for this functionality i use this code:

```
var totalDriversPerAffiliate = _glManager.GetTotalDriversPerAffiliate<ReportItemDriversPerAffiliate>();

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(totalDriversPerAffiliate.GetType());

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ser.Serialize(ms, totalDriversPerAffiliate);
            ms.Position = 0;

            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(ms);
            string res = r.ReadToEnd();

            var context = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
            context.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=TotalDriversPerAffiliate.xml");
            context.ContentType = "application/txt";

            byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res);
            return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
```

But, in response file I have fields in xml which have values of class properties, not values of WCF display name attributes(have "AffiliateName", want "affiliate_name"), how I can manually serialize this class and have fields in xml like display name attribute of class? And, I don't want adding additional xml attributes to this class and I don't want create separate method in web service which return this data as xml response.

Answer (score 0):

The XmlSerializer ignores the DataMember Attribute. Try the NetDataContractSerializer.